# Missing return statement after if-else

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Some compilers (Intel icc, pgi/nvc++) issue "missing return statement" warning for functions like below, while others (gcc, clang) do not issue warnings even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`:

Is the code below legal according to the standard?

This is a minimal reproducible example of my code that gives the warning. Simplifying it to, say, just a single function removes the warning.

```
// test.cpp
#include <climits>
#include <cstddef>

template<class T, std::size_t N>
class Test
{
public:

    class Inner;

private:
    static constexpr std::size_t NB_ = sizeof(std::size_t) * CHAR_BIT;
    static constexpr std::size_t NI_ = (N + NB_ - 1) / NB_;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
class Test<T, N>::Inner
{
public:

    Inner() : b_{0}, j_{0} {}

    friend bool operator!= (Inner x, Inner y)
    {
        if constexpr(J_ > 0)
            return x.j_ != y.j_ || x.b_ != y.b_;
        else
            return x.b_ != y.b_;
    }

private:
    static constexpr std::size_t J_ = NI_ - 1;
    std::size_t b_;
    std::size_t j_;
};

int main()
{
    Test<int, 50>::Inner x, y;
    int a, b;
    x.b_ = a; y.b_ = b;
    x != y;
}
```

Compilation:

```
> nvc++ test.cpp -std=c++17
"test.cpp", line 30: warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "operator!="
      }
      ^
          detected during instantiation of class "Test<T, N>::Inner [with T=int, N=50UL]" at line 41
```

Comment: False warning from nvc++, gcc/clang/msvc doesn't warn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard says this, see [[stmt.return]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.return#2):

> Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with a *cv* `void` return type is equivalent to a `return` with no operand. Otherwise, **flowing off the end of a function other than `main` results in undefined behavior**.

Your `operator !=` does exactly that. It never flows off the end of the function since all control paths end with a `return`.

Hence the code is correct, and the compiler's diagnostic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could those projects be set to compile as an earlier standard of C++?

Some older compilers don't like returns in the middle of code blocks (there are also those that don't like variable identifiers anywhere other than at the start of code blocks).

For those that do complain I just code as:

```
ret_type f(...)
{
    ret_type result = DEFAULT_VALUE; //default value defined elsewhere
    if (condition)
        result = value_1; //presumed valid ret_type value
    else
        result = value_2; //presumed valid ret_type value
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's not been true for any version of standard C++, and such a compiler would be a complete piece of trash.  You may get warnings about multiple return points from static analysis tools depending on your coding guidelines.... but even then the tool should never generate the warning shown in the question.

Comment: Also, the presence of `constexpr if` in the code rules out any archaic language version.

Answer (score 0):

I had some functions where only specific results were acceptable in order to `return`, exactly how your setup is. If it truly is a niche case where both `if` statements will be false (emphasis on niche), then there is something wrong and an exception can be thrown.

In my case, after the last `if` clause, I add:

```cpp
throw std::invalid_argument("\nx  and y cannot be compared\n)");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your code to compile without warnings (Intel ICC 2021.3.0), use `__builtin_unreachable()` to tell the compiler that control flow will never reach the end:

```
friend bool operator!= (Inner x, Inner y)
{
    if constexpr(J_ > 0)
        return x.j_ != y.j_ || x.b_ != y.b_;
    else
        return x.b_ != y.b_;
    __builtin_unreachable();
}
```